# Modify existing url validation regular expression to accept few more urls in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, validation, url

At present I am using:

```
/^(ht|f)tp(s?)\:\/\/[0-9a-zA-Z]([-.\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z])*(:(0-9)*)*(\/?)([a-zA-Z0-9\-\.\?    \,\'\/\\\+&amp;%\$#_]*)?$/
```

as my regular expression for validating URL.

This is failing to check for URLs like:

domain.com, www.domain.com, m.some.com, m.some.com?test=test, http://www.some.com/?param=%20test

Can someone help me in modifying this? I have few functionality already working fine on this. So couldn't search for a complete new one.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give this a whirl - you were really close:

```
/^((ht|f)tp(s?)\:\/\/)?[0-9a-zA-Z]([-.\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z])*(\.[a-zA-Z0-9\-_]+)+(:(0-9)*)*((\/?)|((\/[a-zA-Z0-9\.\-_]+)+)?)(\?[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.\?    \,\'\/\\\+&amp;%\$#=\.\-_]*)?$/;
```

Comment: The problem with this expression is that it is accepting any characters like "ajnfgf" "23724" etc.

Comment: @Daemonthread - good catch - there's now at least one '.[character]' requirement...  so, ajnfgf.q will work, which in the new DNS world might actually be a domain, if someone wants to spend 150k to register .q :)

Comment: Port # doesn't work unless surrounded by [] instead of (), right?

Answer (score 1):

As a first approximation, this will solve your problem:

```
/^((ht|f)tp(s?)\:\/\/)?[0-9a-zA-Z]([-.\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z])*(:(0-9)*)*(\/?)((?:&amp;|[a-zA-Z0-9\-_=.?,'\/+%\$#])*)?$/
```

Comment: @Brian: You are right, just fixed it. Your solution doesn't seem to work for some other very common patterns, though ;-) Try "http://www.some.com/dir/page.html" or "http://www.some.com/dir/page.html?p=1", won't match ...

Comment: Also, didn't see the rest of your comment - you're absolutely right I didn't put "." in the list of characters ... updated.